# Images in Assets with .JPG (in capital letters) file extension don't appear in editor

Tags: assets, wysiwyg, editor

I had a client run into trouble uploading an image in Assets and then trying to drop it in to the WYSIWYG editor. If the file had a **.JPG** extension — in capital letters — the image would only appear as a file link in the editor.

Lowercasing the file extension allowed the image to drop into the editor as expected.

See: http://than.to/io3